# Div content load using Ajax and MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have several buttons which should change content of  region on the page.  I've read numerous tutorials how can lazy load can be implemented using ajax, but unfortunately with no success. Here is my html:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <button id="btn_goals">Goals</button>
        <button id="btn_achievements">Achievements</button>
    </div>

    <div id="region_content"></div>

</div>
```

and here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#btn_goals').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Goals")',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#region_content').html(data);
        }
    });
});

$("#btn_achievements").on("click", function () {
    ......
});
```

});

what is the problem?

********** EDIT ************

Well, I changed url in ajax parameters from url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Goals")' to url: '/Goals/Index' and it starts work fine. What is the reason?

Comment: @Url.Action("Index", "Goals") does this get parsed in the server?

Comment: I set breakpoints at onclick method and Index method of GoalsController. The first fires but the second doesn't

Comment: Let's see your controller, have you set it to allow HttpPost ?

Comment: If you look at your javascript console, do you see the request?

Comment: your controller `Index` action?

Comment: Concole output: POST http://localhost:45334/@Url.Action(%22Index%22,%20%22Goals%22) 404 (Not Found)

Comment: My target GoalController has the only Index method with httpPost attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try following the following steps:

1. Use `console.log("Inside Success function"+ data);` to test whether the required data is being returned from the controller method.

Use `Ctrl+Shift+I` in your browser to view the console. If Successful:

2. Use:

```
var div = document.getElementById("region_content");
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + data;
```

3. Make sure your type conversions are done right.
4. Also specify type: `POST` in your ajax function.

If you do not see 'Inside Success function' on your console, there might be something wrong with your controller function.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I see concole output: POST localhost:45334/@Url.Action(%22Index%22,%20%22Goals%22) 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I changed url in ajax parameters from url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Goals")' to url: '/Goals/Index' and it starts work fine. May be this will help.

Comment: My controller code is simply autogenerated. It has only Index method which returns View()

Comment: Where are you getting your data from? Any ways if it works it works ;p

Comment: Yes, it works finally ;) But I don't understand why it doesn' like @Url.Action.

Comment: From where are you receiving the data that you are adding to your  "region_content" div?

Comment: Well, it is just test html with no data (just a red rectangle). It located in Views/Goals/Index.cshtml

Comment: When you use url: '/Goals/Index' you are being redirected to that page. The data is not being displayed in your div. When you use @Url.Action some data is to be returned from the function ("function","controller"). Then you can use the data returned in your div. Although it is possible, I believe it is preferable to use some function other than Index as it routed.